# Trying out Entity Framework Code-first; is the usage any different from Database-first?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

When working with EF (v4,5,6) I have always used Database-first (I was mistakenly under the impression this was the only way to generate Entities from existing tables, EDMX, etc). But today I tryed Code-first, and it can also generate the POCOs (in a different way, no EDMX, different connection string, less cr8p lying around, etc..!)

So far, the usage of EF for CRUD appears to be exactly the same, can anyone who has used both please confirm there is nothing different (in usage), or gotchas I should be aware of?

And a supplementary question is, can I generate both in the same project ? (Not that i want to, but existing proj has EDMX within a folder, can I create another folder and generate Code-First Entities (different set of tables only), so i end up with DBContext and DBContext2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the usage is the same. If you check the generated code you'll see they use the same System.Data.Entity.DbSet properties and they both inherit from the same System.Data.Entity.DbContext class.

Yes, you can generate both in the same project, but does not makes much sense, because you have to maintain both of them if the DB changes.